# Add/remove form inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `form` with one initial empty `input` field that I want to clone using a `Add` button and to remove with a `Remove` one.

As it's not recommended to use index for the keys with dynamic forms, I tried to use `uniqid` module. But each time the `state` is updating, keys are renewed and I don't have unique data to identify each input of the form. I can add some items, but can't remove.

`input` fields have no unique values, no `id`, how can I do ?

```
const Form = () => {
  const update = e => {};
  const items = [{ content: "", color: "" }];

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {items.map((item, idx) => (
        <input
          htmlFor={`item_${idx}`}
          value={item.content}
          onChange={update("item", idx)}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={e => dispatch(add(idx))}>Add</button>
      <button onClick={e => dispatch(remove(idx))}>Remove</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply extend your existing `items` to have unique `id` property - at its very simplest, you may assign the value of maximum used `id` increased by 1 to that property - I guess, it'll do the trick for most of practical use cases:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([{id:0,value:''}]),
      onRowAdd = () => {
          const maxId = Math.max(...inputs.map(({id}) => id))
          setInputs([...inputs, {id:maxId+1, value:''}])
      }
```

With that, you'll have unique `id` to anchor to as you delete rows:

```
onRowRemove = idToDelete => setInputs(inputs.filter(({id}) => id != idToDelete))
```

Following is the demo of this concept:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM
      
const Form = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([{id:0,value:''}]),
        onInput = (id,value) => {
          const inputsCopy = [...inputs],
                itemToModify = inputsCopy.find(item => item.id == id)
          itemToModify.value = value
          setInputs(inputsCopy)
        },
        onRowAdd = () => {
          const maxId = Math.max(...inputs.map(({id}) => id))
          setInputs([...inputs, {id:maxId+1, value:''}])
        },
        onRowRemove = idToDelete => setInputs(inputs.filter(({id}) => id != idToDelete)),
        onFormSubmit = e => (e.preventDefault(), console.log(inputs))
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} >
      {
        inputs.map(({id,value}) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <input 
              onKeyUp={({target:{value}}) => onInput(id,value)}
            />
            <input type="button" onClick={onRowAdd} value="Add" />
            <input type="button" onClick={() => onRowRemove(id)} value="Remove" />
          </div>
        ))
      }
      <input type="submit" value="Log Form Data" />
    </form>
  )
}

render (
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a variable that starts from 0 and adds 1 every time you add a button. That way you will keep track of everyone. Here's an example

```
let i = 0
const add () => {
//your function to add
i++
//remember i will be the id now
}
```