# How do I dynamically add multiple Input fields in react with an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where I can add additional fields by clicking a button. How do I achieve this while also calling setState for each field when onChange event is triggered?

[image]

Example: Add Address

So what I want to achieve is

Address 1

Address 2

Address 3

(OnClick) ‘adds’ Address 4, Address 5...6,7,8 
Then having a setState for each.

Comment: Can you share some code that you have right now?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60265345/11299053) address your concern?

Comment: If you would post some of your code, I (or someone else) could've suggested some relevant code that fits in to solve your issue.