# How to dynamically push added inputs value to array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have React component where I can dynamically add new text inputs. So, I need to push the values from the inputs to array.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
function FormPage({ setData }) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  const addItem = (setItem) => setItem((ing) => [...ing, newItem]);

  return (
    {Array.from(Array(counter)).map((c, index) =>
      <TextField 
        key={index} 
        label="Item"
        onChange={() => setItem(i=> [...i, (this.value)])} 
      />
    )}

    <Button onClick={handleCounter}>Add one more item</Button>
  )
}
```

Here is example in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-sound-t2cfy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you please share your code on sandbox or stackblitz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add/remove form inputs dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263520/add-remove-form-inputs-dynamically)

Comment: @RishabVaigankar i added the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, you are using two-way data binding with your `TextField` component, so you also need to pass a `value` prop.
2. Secondly, to get the current value of `TextField`, we don't use `this.value`. Rather, the callback to `onChange` takes an argument of type `Event` and you can access the current value as follows

```
<TextField
...
onChange={(e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    // Do something with value
}}
/>
```

3. You cannot return multiple children from a component without wrapping them by single component. You are simply returning multiple `TextField` components at the same level, which is also causing an error. Try wrapping them in `React.Fragment` as follows

```
...
return (
   <React.Fragment>
   {/* Here you can return multiple sibling components*/}
   </React.Fragment>
);
```

4. You are mapping the `TextField` components using `counter` which is equal to the length of `item` array. In `handleCounter`, we'll add a placeholder string to accomodate the new `TextField` value.

```
...
const handleCounter = () => {
    setCounter(prev => prev+1); // Increment the counter
    setItem(prev => [...prev, ""]); // Add a new value placeholder for the newly added TextField
}
return (
   <React.Fragment>
     { /* Render only when the value of counter and length of item array are the same  */
     counter === item.length && (Array.from(Array(counter).keys()).map((idx) => (
         <TextField
          key={idx}
          value={item[idx]}
          label="Item"
          onChange={(e) => {
              const val = e.target.value;
              setItem(prev => {
                  const nprev = [...prev]
                  nprev[idx] = val;
                  return nprev;
              })
          }}
         />
     )))}
     <br />
     <Button onClick={handleCounter}>Add one more item</Button>
   </React.Fragment>
);
```

5. Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-glitter-7b6xi?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
// Changes made here
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  console.log("item 1:", item[0], "item 2:", item[1],item);

  const handleCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
  const addItem = (newItem) => setItem((ing) => [...ing, newItem]);

  return (
    <>
      {Array.from(Array(counter)).map((c, index) => (
        <input
          type="text"
          key={index}
//Changes made here
          value={item[index]}
          label="Item"
// Changes made here
          onChange={(event) => setItem({...item, [index]:event.target.value })}
        />
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleCounter}>Add one more item</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Instead of using an array to store the input values I recommend using an object as it's more straight-forward.

If you wanted to use an array you can replace the `onChange` event with the following:

```
onChange={(event) => {
            const clonedArray = item.slice()
            clonedArray[index] = event.target.value
            setItem(clonedArray)
          }}
```

It's slightly more convoluted and probably slightly less optimal, hence why I recommend using an object.

If you want to loop through the object later you can just use `Object.entries()` like so:

```
[...Object.entries(item)].map(([key, value]) => {console.log(key, value)})
```

[Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for `Object.entries()`.

Answer (score 1):

**codeSolution**: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-cache-dlnku?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(["a", "b"]);

  const handleCounter = () => {
    console.log(item, "item");
    setItem([...item, ""]);
  };

  const setInput = (index) => (evt) => {
    item.splice(index, 1, evt.target.value);
    setItem([...item]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {item.map((c, index) => {
        return (
          <input
            type="text"
            key={index}
            label="Item"
            value={c}
            onChange={setInput(index)}
          />
        );
      })}

      <button onClick={handleCounter}>Add one more item</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have solved for you . check if this works for you , if any issues tell me